# How to use concatenation with a variable used in a JavaScript JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, concatenation

I'm trying to use a variable that contains the name of a HTML element in a JQuery function for a radio button.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
var oldRadioValue = $('input[name="correct10")"]:checked').val();
```

But due to the radio button being created dynamically I need to do something like this:

```
var radioName = "correct"+questionCount;

var oldRadioValue = $('input[name=radioName]:checked').val();
```

When I check the console.log() I am getting undefined...
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `$('input[name=radioName]').val()` will work , jquery knows to get the value of the checked one

Comment: I haven't tried all browsers but I did try and test so many different ways including yours Scott and it always returned undefined

Comment: my comment works ,   the problem probably was that there should be double quotes around radioName `[name="radioName"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to it like this do this

```
var oldRadioValue = $('input[name="' + radioName + '"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: I tried so many variations of this but to no avail. but this works. Thanks :)

Comment: like I said in the comment , you do not need `:checked` in the selector.  the reason this one is working is because you properly included the double quotes around the name value

Answer (score 1):

You can either use concatenation like this:

```
 var oldRadioValue = $('input[name="'+radioName+'"]:checked').val()
```

Or the newer template literal syntax:

```
var oldRadioValue = $(`input[name="${radioName}"]:checked`).val();
```

Comment: Thanks for you're quick response. I made an edit to you're first solution to make it work. The newer template solution you gave gives me a jQuery exception :(

Answer (score 0):

Your need string concatenation to make this work.

```
var oldRadioValue = $('input[name=' + radioName +  ']:checked').val();
```